# Need to pull the value from json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the value of email from JSON but i think my code is incorrect. I am echoing out the value but I am not getting a value to print, Please take a look at the following and let me know if it is incorrect

```
$body='{object: "customer"
created: 1395881542
id: cus_3jvcniqcnhNWID
livemode: true
description: null
email: "support@support.com"
delinquent: false
metadata:
subscriptions:
object: "list"
count: 1
url: "/v1/customers/cus_3jvcniqcnhNWID/subscriptions"
data:
id: sub_3jvcYUNI2ZeM6W
plan:
interval: "month"
name: "Monthly"
created: 1395872091
amount: 999
currency: "gbp"
id: UK DJs Monthly
object: "plan"
livemode: true

 "}';
 $event_json = json_decode($body);
 $getit = $event_json->email;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JSON! JSON requires the keys and strings to be quoted and the items separated by a comma. After adding the required quotes it works fine:

```
$body='{"object": "customer",
"created": 1395881542,
"id": "cus_3jvfrgrcniqcnhNWID",
"livemode": true,
"description": null,
"email": "support@support.com"}';
 $event_json = json_decode($body);
 $getit = $event_json->email; // support@support.com
```